# phpmyadmin on debian with nginx

Tags: nginx, permissions, debian

I'm trying to use Deabian's package of phpmyadmin with nginx. In tutorials they create symlink to the phpmyadmin source files from virtualhost, like this:

```
$ln -s /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ /var/www/host.com/phpmyadmin
```

I think my first problem is, that nginx is running under nobody user, but the owner of phpmyadmin files is root. I tried to change owner to nginx user but it didn't helped. The second problem might be usage of symlink, so I tried enable nginx to follow symlinks:

```
disable_symlinks off;
```

It also didn't help. The server is still returning

> No input file specified.

when i try to view phpmyadmin index. The http request generate this errors:

> 2015/05/12 02:07:02 [error] 4017#0: *35 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/host.com/phpmyadmin/index.php (Operation not permitted)" while reading response header from upstream

What I'm doing wrong? And what's the proper way to make it work with ability to upgrade phpmyadmin via apt-get? Thanks.

Comment: try create a user `www` for example and give him rights recursively on `/var/www`, and one `/usr/share/phpmyadmin`, don't forget the `-R` parameter when you chown

Comment: @Bob0t /var/www is owned by nobody - the user under nginx process runs. As I written I already tried change owner of the phpmyadmin folder to nobody and it didn't help.

Comment: i had many probs to install it, then i used [this config](https://gist.github.com/denys281/8931843) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution. I forgot to add the phpmyadmin directory to PHP open_basedir. Now everything is working properly. Thanks all users for advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the package manager, you shouldn't create the link or change users on your own -- the package manager should handle setting permissions and aliases correctly.

I suggest undoing what you've done then running `dpkg-reconfigure --plow phpmyadmin` from the shell/command line in order to force apt/dpkg to reconfigure the package. Make sure you select nginx in the screen where it prompts for which webserver to use.

Comment: I can't select nginx since it's not there, see screenshot:
[link](http://ctrlv.cz/Lzz1)

Comment: Yeas I did, but the configuration is now heavily changed since install.